# Calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2} te^t dt\right)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have an assignment where one problem is to calculate two expressions, one with a given function and one with a general function. Previous assignments have been very picky in the grading and I've lost points for (in my opinion) very small details, so my question is if anyone can find anything about the solutions below that is missing, not clear enough, make too many intermediate steps at the same time, etc. Do the methods seem sound? Do they make assumptions that should instead be made explicit?

a) Calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2} te^t dt\right)$.

My solution is as follows:

First I calculate the integral in the parenthesis using partial integration with the choice of $t$ as the function to take the derivative of since it will be $1$ which simplifies things:
$
\begin{align*}
        \int_0^{x^2} te^t dt &= \Big[te^t\Big]_0^{x^2} - \int_0^{x^2} e^t dt \\
                             &= x^2 e^{x^2} - \Big[e^t\Big]_0^{x^2} \\
                             &= x^2 e^{x^2} - (e^{x^2} - e^0) \\
                             &= x^2 e^{x^2} - e^{x^2} + 1 \\
                             &= e^{x^2}(x^2 - 1) + 1
    \end{align*}
$

Then take the derivative of this expression with respect to $x$ and using the product rule:
$
\begin{align*}
        \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^2}(x^2 - 1) + 1\right) &= e^{x^2} \cdot 2x + e^{x^2} \cdot 2x (x^2 - 1) \\
                                                      &= e^{x^2}(2x + 2x(x^2 - 1)) \\
                                                      &= e^{x^2}(2x + 2x^3 - 2x) \\
                                                      &= 2e^{x^2}x^3
    \end{align*}
$

and $2e^{x^2}x^3$ is the final answer.

b) Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function. Calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt\right)$. The answer will of course depend on $f$ but cannot include any references to integrals or primitive functions.

My solution is as follows:

First, expand the expression in the paranthesis:

Then take the derivative term by term and using the chain rule:

$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(F(x^2) - F(0)\bigg)
        = f(x^2) \cdot 2x - f(0)
        = 2x f(x^2)$

Note that $f(0)$ disappears since we take the derivative with respect to $x$ and not $t$. Regardless of what function $F$ is, its value will not contain any $x$. The final answer is $2x f(x^2)$ and it only depends on $x$ and $f$ according to the problem statement.

Edit: As pointed out in a comment that seems to be gone now, $\frac{d}{dx}(F(0)) \neq f(0)$ so the last part is incorrect but gives the same result. I'll update this at some point.

Comment: "$\frac{d}{dx}(F(0)) \neq f(0)$", $F(0)$ is a number (a constant!) so its derivative with respect to $x$ is...? Apart from this but relating to your approach and perhaps an alternative (intended?) approach: have you seen the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part)? If so, this seems like a problem designed to apply this theorem (combined with the chain rule).

Comment: @StackTD Sounds reasonable and probably more elegant, I'll have a look at an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: You'll notice the extra advantage in the case where it becomes far more difficult, or maybe even impossible, to find a primitive function. The FTOC-approach to this kind of problems avoids having to find/use a primitive function.

Answer (score 1):

More concise:

Let $g(x):=\int_0^xf(t)$ and $h(x):=g(x^2)$ (so that $h(x)=\int_0^{x^2}f(t)$).

Then $g'(x)=f(x)$ and $h'(x)=2xg'(x^2)$ (application of chain rule)

We conclude that $h'(x)=2xf(x^2)$.

This can be applied on suitable functions like $f(t)=te^t$.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to just use [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\frac d {dx} \int _0 ^{x^2}te^t dt = x^2e^{x^2}\cdot 2x = 2x^3e^{x^2}$$

For f(x), we have
$$\frac d {dx} \int _0 ^{x^2}f(t) dt = f(x^2)\cdot 2x = 2xf(x^2)$$

Unless it was asked by your instructor to use a first principles approach to obtaining these results, this rule should be perfectly valid and usable.

Comment: Some previous problems in the same assignment are about the fundamental theorem of calculus so I would guess that is some kind of implication. Very useful rule in any case!

Answer (score 0):

notice that by definition:
$$\frac d{dy}\int_0^y te^tdt=ye^y$$
if we let $y=x^2$ we get:
$$\frac d{dx}\int_0^{x^2}te^tdt=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac d{dy}\int_0^yte^tdt=2xye^y=2x^3e^{x^2}$$
the same thing can be done for the second question

Comment: I should mention that the first line is just the fundamental theorem of calculus